# Which is the best city in Canada for data science job opportunities?

Tags: immigration, canada, indian-citizens, job-hunting

Which city out of Toronto and Vancouver have better data science opportunities? 
Is there a different city with better data science opportunity other than the two above?

Comment: Your question asks for opinions, which makes it unsuitable for this site. Given your skills, you could run an analysis for yourself.

Comment: I'd add Ottawa to the list, and consider them to have similar opportunities.  Of course, opportunities alone don't make for a good decision metric.